# Integers as the only valid inputs

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is ask users for two inputs, if one of the inputs is less than zero or if the input is some string then ask for the inputs again. The only valid input are numbers >=0. So you can't have something like -1 or cat as inputs.

Attempt 1:

```
number_of_books = input("What is the number of books in the game?: ")
number_of_chairs = input("What is the number of chairs in the game?: ")
while int(number_of_books) < 0 or int(number_of_chairs) < 0 or isinstance(number_of_books, str) or isinstance(number_of_chairs, str):
    print("Input cannot be less than 0 or cannot be some string.")
    number_of_books = input("What is the number of books in the game?: ")
    number_of_chairs = input("What is the number of chairs in the game?: ")
```

But from this I realized that the input are always strings so it will ask for input again.

Attempt 2:

```
number_of_books = int(input("What is the number of books in the game?: "))
number_of_chairs = int(input("What is the number of chairs in the game?: "))
while number_of_books < 0 or number_of_chairs < 0 or isinstance(number_of_books, str) or isinstance(number_of_chairs, str):
    print("Input cannot be less than 0 or cannot be some string.")
    number_of_books = int(input("What is the number of books in the game?: "))
    number_of_chairs = int(input("What is the number of chairs in the game?: "))
```

But with this one I realized that you cannot do int('some string')

So I'm wondering if there is a way to do this or is this something not possible?

Comment: Did you try to input a non-integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `while` loop for each input, so only the invalid one is asked again. By using `while True`, you ask for input once, and break once it's valid. Try to convert to `int`, which raises `ValueError` if that cannot be done. Exceptions cause the custom error to be printed, and the loop restarted.

```
while True:
    books_input = input("What is the number of books in the game?: ")
    try:
        number_of_books = int(books_input)
        if number_of_books < 0:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print('Input must be an integer and cannot be less than zero')
    else:
        break
```

You'd need to do this for each input (maybe there are more than two?), so it makes sense to create a function to do the heavy lifting.

```
def non_negative_input(message):
    while True:
        input_string = input(message)
        try:
            input_int = int(books_input)
            if input_int < 0:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print('Input must be an integer and cannot be less than zero')
        else:
            break
    return input_int
```

Calling it:

```
non_negative_input("What is the number of books in the game?: ")
```

Comment: As a suggestion to the OP, this would also be wise to flip into a function, eg "prompt_for_non_negative_integer(text)", which displays 'text' upon input() and returns the valid integer.

Comment: might be too much to take in at once, but i'll add a quick note at the end

Comment: Make a backup of the file once you have it working, then try to flip it to a function. Should take about the same time as adding a note, or at least only a few extra minutes if it's your first go-round. :-)

Comment: ok reading through OP's history, it looks like it should be easy enough to handle. will update entirely

Comment: Btw, I thought I was replying to the OP, didn't notice I was replying to the answer-er. Thus my tone is a bit confusing in retrospect. Sorry about that. :-P

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to coerce the answer to int() and catch any exceptions, for example:

```
while True:
    try:
        number_of_books = int(raw_input('Enter number of books:'))
        if number_of_books < 0:
            raise ValueError('must be greater than zero')
    except ValueError, exc:
        print("ERROR: %s" % str(exc))
        continue
    break
```

Probably you should put this in a function, and make the prompt a variable (to allow re-use).

Comment: Please use `except ValueError as exc:`.  The other syntax is deprecated in Python 2.7 and removed altogether in Python 3.x.

Comment: Only available in 2.6+. I have no idea what version he is using, and didn't want him to encounter an error if OP had older than 2.6.

Comment: @user590028 He's almost certainly in Python3 since he's using `input()` instead of `raw_input()` and `print(foo)` instead of `print foo`. Basically instead of safeguarding him against an error if his version of Python was too old, you gave him erroneous code because his version of Python was too new! :)

Comment: I don't mean to be argumentative -- but this is not correct. input() and print() are both available in 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Use the try except method

```
while stringval = input("What is the number you want to enter"):
  try:
    intval = int(stringval)
    if intval > -1:
      break
  except ValueError:
    print 'Invalid answer, try again'

# Process intval now
```